# Bodenstein Hydrogen Iodide equilibirum experiment query

Tags: equilibrium

[image]

This text says that the same amount of HI was formed during the bulbs' time spent in the thermostat baths, regardless of the varying initial amount of HI each bulb contained.

Is this true? I always thought equilibrium meant only that, at a specific temperature, the forward reaction rate = reverse reaction rate. Does anyone know where to find Bodenstein's original published article on this experiment?

Comment: Type "Bodenstain works" on Google, or "Bodenstein Hydrogen Iodide". You will get all the information you need.

Comment: You seem to forget that you are describing a chemical reaction and at the start of the experiment there was no chemical equilibrium, you have the pure compounds.

Comment: You could check any textbook of *Physical Chemistry* and the kinetics of reversible reaction